# Windows Phone 8.1 File Picker resuming issue

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, filepicker

I am developing a Windows Phone 8.1 application where on appbarbutton click, I open a file picker. The app works fine when I run it via visual studio.

But when I run it on the device without being connected to Visual studio,the file picker launches and shows photos library and after I select a photo and click the ok button the screen says resuming for 2-3 secs and the app crashes!

I have tried setting the Start action of Debug to "Do not launch,but debug my code when it starts" and tried suspend and shutdown option in lifecyle process when the file picker screen is showed. The app calls the Onsuspending method when I do that. But after my selection the app does not call the OnActivated method and shows "resuming..." for a long time until I stop debugging.

Comment: I have stuck on same problem

Comment: Did u refer this https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br207847

Comment: Do you have any code on the `OnActivated` event

Answer (score 0):

I have beeing also stuck on this error and even this example [File picker sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/File-picker-sample-9f294cba) has not helped me.

Have manualy check activation event of my page and also NavigatedTo event. Comment all the code inside, uncomment line by line and found bug. So, can recommend to do the same. Was unable to debug also even with "Do not launch,but debug my code when it starts" checked like described in manual

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. After selecting image, os wrote Resuming.. and crash. Problem was with my MediaCapture. First use mediaCapture.stopPreviewAsync(); to stop preview and than you must release the mediaCapture.
Before you call fileOpener use this code:

`newCapture.Dispose();`